# After after updating packages, running library(tidyverse), pipe operator not working

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, operator-keyword

When I apply run

```
labor<-labor %>% mutate(union=unior)
```

I am getting the following error.

> Error in split_chain(match.call(), env = env) :
> could not find function "split_chain"

Answer (score 1):

Magrittr 2.0 update impacts the use of {} within a pipe chain, see https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/11/magrittr-2-0-is-here/

That was it for me.

Comment: installing magrittr as a named dependency, and loading the library worked for me. -> `install.packages("magrittr"); library(magrittr)`